# self-answered questions from other sources

Tags: discussion, questions, self-answer, external-links

I found the answer to a problem I had on some site (not SO). Is it appropriate for SO to:

- ask the question I had
- reply to it myself (so far [this is even encouraged](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer))
- ... with the data from this other site (so zero contribution from me)
- ... giving credits to the site and answer

Assuming the license of the original content allows that (which also means it is explicit).

The core of my question (this one) is: is it OK to answer with someone else' answer without any contribution from me? As opposed to ask a question and answer it myself with the solution I found myself.

Comment: What is the license on the other content you intend to include?

Comment: @TZHX: there is no explicit license. Let's assume that it is OK from the other site perspective.

Comment: No, let's not assume that. I don't post things on my blog so that people can just re-post them anywhere they want. If people want their original content to be here, they'll post it here.

Comment: What I meant by "Let's assume that it is OK" is that the licensing part is clear and it is OK to copy the content. I am interested by the SO perspective - the other one is something the poster on SO must handle beforehand.

Comment: If there's no explicit license, then it's all rights reserved and so posting it here would be a violation of copyright.

Comment: @TZHX: please read my comment above

Comment: @WoJ I did, but was responding to your comment above your comment above (above above? above.)

Comment: You might want to add that to the question so people don't keep hard-stopping on the same point.

Comment: I dunno, I thought it was fairly obvious what the OP meant by "assume". I think the point the others were trying to make though is that someone else might come across your question and think it's OK without realizing that the assumption was being made, and start reusing content without permission just because "this meta post said I can".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming* you could find content with a license permissive enough to allow this, I don't see any issue with it. Assuming your question is a *good* question, and doesn't just sit there to prop up the answer (which is the standard we should judge any questions by).

I think it would be common courtesy to make the answer *community wiki* so as to avoid the possible interpretation that you're simply trying to take other's work and build rep from it -- this is typically the suggested course when posting answers from another user's comment on the site.

---

* : Honestly, I think this is going to be the limiting factor here. Consider that if there were two identical *Stack Overflows* -- which has a fairly permissive license -- users would not be able to meet the attribution requirements necessary to do what you suggest doing between them.

Comment: Good comment in paragraph two - this is what I will do when needed. As for the first one, the idea is not to loose good answers to good questions found elsewhere - assuming the license permits :)